# Angular/Cordova: MIME Type issue on android device

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova

I have created a Cordova application which simply serves the default Angular welcome page when creating a a new project. It works fine in the browser. It works fine when run it on an emulator via Android Studio.

When I run it on my android device I get a blank page and the following error is available in the console:

```
polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js:1 Failed to load module script: The 
server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type 
checking is enforced for module scripts per 
HTML spec.

main-es2015.734c1bff4ed0a6bbbd29.js:1 Failed to load module script: The 
server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type 
checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I can fix this by editing by `dist/<project>/index.html` created by Angular. Angular no longer includes the `type="text/javascript"` parameters in the `<script>` tags it creates. Instead they look like this:

```
<script src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.5728f680576ca47e99fe.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.7f43b971448d2fb49202.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="main-es2015.734c1bff4ed0a6bbbd29.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.43ecaae92d6e77bfb1c5.js" nomodule></script>
```

If I change that to `type="text/javascript"` the app runs correctly on my device.

How can I tell Cordova to include the correct MIME type headers when serving the javascript files?

Answer (score 2):

you can update your tsconfig.json in angular project:

```
"target": "es5",
```

if you don't want to change the target in tsconfig,
you can use before_prepare hook file to replace content in index.html

in folder hooks add new folder and name it "before_prepare"...
inside before_prepare folder add new js file and name it for example "01_switch_configuration.js"

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var rootdir = process.argv[2];

function replace_string_in_file(filename, to_replace, replace_with) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
    var result = data.replace(new RegExp(to_replace, "g"), replace_with);
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, result, 'utf8');
}
if (rootdir) {
    var filestoreplace = ["www/index.html"];
    filestoreplace.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
        var fullfilename = path.join(rootdir, val);
        if (fs.existsSync(fullfilename)) {
            replace_string_in_file(fullfilename, 'type="module"', 'type="text/javascript"');
        } else {
            console.log("missing: " + fullfilename);
        }
    });
}
```

and run you project

Answer (score 0):

The `assets` can be fixed by defining a `before_compile` [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/#ways-to-define-hooks), which runs a shell script:

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' ./platforms/android/assets/index.html
```

These regular expressions probably should match `nomodule` and `type="module"` as the `original`.