# Angular 8 + Cordova 6 = blank page

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I whish I could run an angular application on an android mobile using Cordova. I made those steps :

Creating cordova projet

```
cordova create myCordova fr.athome.myCordova MyCordova
 => Creating a new cordova project
```

Adding android platform

```
cordova platform add android
 => Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
```

Adding browser platform

```
cordova platform add browser
 => Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@^6.0.0
```

Starting project in browser

```
cordova emulate browser
```

[image: Cordova projet in browser]

Starting project in emulator android

```
cordova emulate android --target="Nexus5XAPI27"
```

[image: Cordova project in Android emulator]

Creating angular project

```
ng new myAngular --routing
```

added 1188 packages from 1050 contributors and audited 18866 packages in 48.704s
Launching angular project in browser

```
ng serve
```

[image: Angular project in browser]

Angular in Cordova : using this tutorial :
https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79

Angular prod in cordova project

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./ --output-path m:/cordova/myCordova/www/
```

[image: Angular prod]

```
index.html modified
```

[image: Index.html modified]
Starting in android emulator

```
cordova emulate android --target="Nexus5XAPI27"
```

[image: Starting in android emulator]

Where is my error(s) ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution, if you add type="text/javascript" for each script tag in index.html, it will work fine !
This is this post : [MIME Type issue on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262722/angular-cordova-mime-type-issue-on-android-device?rq=1) which gave me the idea to add the type mime.
In my case it works fine ;-)
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update tsConfig.json and replace ***"target": "es2015"* by *"target": "es5"***

Don't forget build with angular

> ng build --prod

before build with cordova

> cordova build android

Comment: Yes, you're rigth, but I think it's a good practice to specify the type mime. Thank's